# Open an unknown file that was saved in Java

Tags: java, file, parsing

I am doing data recovery for a company. They need one type of file specifically, created in a java software package from the government. Filenames are lost, but the files themselves contain the project name. You can only find these when you actually open them in that software though, the files themselves do not contain any plain text. There are many thousands of files, so we can't expect someone to manually open them and update the filenames.

An added difficulty is that there are several different formats of these files: the most recent version of the software can't just open files from the previous version, it needs to "convert" them. This gives me the impression that the files are simply Objects that have been saved, and with each software version they change their Class so much that old files can't be cast into their new Class anymore. Or something. It's been a while since I programmed in java. :)

In any case, I "simply" want to read a single property of that object. But I don't have its Class to parse it with (which can be one of many, depending on the software version the file was saved with). I have the jar files from that software, but am hoping I don't need to start analysing that whole software package to see what it does exactly.

So I finally get to my question: can I open such a file (assuming it's indeed a "saved Object"), and somehow parse its contents as plain text? I'm sure that once that is done, I can retrieve where the project name is saved - hopefully in the same place across software versions.

Comment: It's hard to say which route will be easier, but I see two directions :) - 1) decompile the jar class files and try to find the place where files are written (just searching for ObjectOutputStream for example might work). This seems like the easier option to me :) - 2) Try to reverse engineer the file format (a good starting point is the serialization spec here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html and more specifically the protocol: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html.

Comment: And one more thing, if the files were indeed written using simply Java's standard serialization and the project name you are after is just a string, then since "The representation of String objects consists of length information followed by the contents of the string encoded in modified UTF-8.", you should be able to find that string, UTF-8 encoded in the file somewhere just by opening it in a Hex editor :)

Comment: Decompiling, which I was initially intimidated by, ended up giving the fastest and best result! Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If they are serialized objects, the file will start with a magic value of 0xACED and then a protocol version number, currently 0x0005.

If so, you can't really parse it other than by deserializing it with Java code, with all the relevant classes available on the CLASSPATH in the relevant versions. The reason is that any serializable class can provide its own code to write to the stream, which therefore only that class will understand correctly.

Comment: I see that the files always start with DFFC 6148 55BE 74F8 ... (perhaps I should have mentioned that in my question), so I'm assuming that rules out serialized objects. Thanks for the info! I guess I'll have to decompile and look where files are written, as xpa1492 suggests.